# Xamarin forms - Selecionar e exibir Imagens

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugin, xamarin-forms

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Xamarin forms e estou precisando de uma funcionalidade em que o usuário posso escolher uma imagem da galeria e que essa imagem possa ser exibida em um controle Image no aplicativo.
Estou trabalhando com o [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) e também tenho experimentado o [FilePicker](https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows), mas até agora nenhum deles tem funcionado comigo.
Estou precisando então de uma boa dica para saber como faço para trabalhar com imagens em xamarin forms.

**CÓDIGO FILEPICKER**

**Chamando o método**

```
public async void SelecionarImagem(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            carregarImagem.CarregaImagem();
            imgAgencia.Source = carregarImagem.fileNameFoto;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(carregarImagem.fileDataImage.FileName))
            {
                imgAgencia.Source = carregarImagem.fileDataImage.FileName;
                await DisplayAlert("Exception", carregarImagem.fileDataImage.FileName, "OK");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Exception", ex.Message, "OK");
        }
    }
```

**Implementação**

```
public FileData fileDataImage { get; set; }

    public async void CarregaImagem()
    {
        FileData filedata = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();

        while (fileDataImage.FileName.Equals(null))
        {
            continue;
        }

        fileDataImage = filedata;
    }
```

Esse sempre dá uma exceção. Fiz meu debug e vi que ele tenta atribuir o resultado da seleção antes mesmo que eu selecione uma imagem da galeria.

Comment: Se está enfrentando um erro específico poste seu código para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: "mas até agora nenhum deles tem funcionado comigo", não funciona por qual motivo ?

Comment: amigo @leonardo silva poderia postar o código, o erro que está recebendo? Sua pergunta está muito pobre de informação! :) Ficamos no aguardo!

Comment: Da uma olhada no código que utilizo com o MediaPlugin para abrir o album de fotos, funciona perfeitamente                 //var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
                //{
                //    PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Small
                //});

Comment: Veja se te ajuda!

Comment: Valeu, vou dar uma olhada aqui.

Comment: @LeonardoSilva conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Bom dia! Ainda não Milton. Estou testando o código do FilePicker, mas está dando uma exceção quando vou fazer a seleção da imagem. Dá uma mensagem de exceção antes mesmo de aparecer a tela de seleção de imagem. `FileData filedata = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();` Esse código é o que chama o seletor de imagens, mas o comando "await" não está sendo respeitado e a aplicação segue a execução. Com relação ao **MediaPlugin**, vou reescrever a aplicação de teste, pois a que eu estou testando não está renderizando a tela de inicio.